# How to not have object join a group when hovered and dropped over the latter in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

By default, when an object is dragged over a group in draw.io, the group is highlighted in purple, signifying that dropping the object will make it part of the group. How do I avoid this? Can I just disable that automatic grouping overall, given that I don't use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start dragging a shape and then click and hold down Alt key. This sould prevent grouping.

Regards,